# Boost bcp : cannot find bcp

Tags: c++, boost

I want to build boost/locale.hpp and I decided to use bcp because I'll build on arm ubuntu(slow..)

to use bcp, I ran the following commands at boost root directory

```
./b2 tools/bcp
```

but I couldn't find bcp anywhere..

Could you tell me where the bcp is or give me any solutions?

Ps. I'm asking this question on other's phone (I borrowed..). When I login stackoverflow.com, I use my google account, but stackoverflow accepts my account as gmail account and shows me "Create new account"... Could you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: You should ask the "PS" part of your question on [meta]. They should be able to help you there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know specifically about Ubuntu, but when I built `bcp` on Windows with `b2` the resulting binary ends up in `dist/bin`. You may find that there's also another copy in a subdirectory.  Try changing to the top level of your boost source and running

```
find . -name 'bcp'
```